# ECS + EFS - files never make their way out of the container

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

I'm trying to do a POC with ECS + EFS (MySQL for a personal site), but the file changes to the mounted volume within docker don't make their way to EFS.

I have it mounted on the container host:

`us-east-1a.fs-#####.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ on /mnt/mysql-data-docker type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.0.0.128,local_lock=none,addr=10.0.0.90)`

My task definition (relevant parts) shows:

```
"mountPoints": [
  {
    "containerPath": "/var/lib/mysql",
    "sourceVolume": "mysql-data",
    "readOnly": null
  }
]
```

and

```
"volumes": [
  {
    "host": {
      "sourcePath": "/mnt/mysql-data-docker"
    },
    "name": "mysql-data"
  }
],
```

I can write a file there, terminate the host, have the new host come up via scaling group and get mounted, and the file is still there, so I know that's working (and EFS shows 12kb on that FS instead of 6kb).

Looking at the running MySQL container:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-128 ~]$ docker inspect e96a7 | jq '.[0].Mounts'
[
  {
    "Source": "/mnt/mysql-data-docker",
    "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
]
```

`/mnt/mysql-data-docker` on the host only shows my test file I verified with. In the container, there's a bunch of stuff in `/var/lib/mysql` but it never makes its way to the host or to EFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its because:

> If you're using the Amazon ECS-Optimized AMI or Amazon Linux AMI's docker packages, the Docker daemon's mount namespace is unshared from the host's at launch. Some other AMIs might also have this behaviour.
>   On any of those, a filesystem mount will not propagate to the Docker daemon until the next time it's restarted.

So running `sudo service docker restart && sudo start ecs` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

When you startup an EC2 instance you can specify a "user data" script that is run at boot time, BEFORE the docker start up

In your case, something like this should work:

```
#cloud-boothook
#!/bin/bash

# Install nfs-utils
sudo yum install -y nfs-utils

# Mount EFS, writing the volume to fstab ensures it will automatically mount even on reboot

    sudo mkdir -p /mnt/mysql-data-docker
    sudo echo "us-east-1a.fs-#####.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/mysql-data-docker nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2" >> /etc/fstab

    sudo mount -a
```

Comment: This isnt true, docker starts up before Userdata runs. The  script I had earlier was failing through userdata as well. The follow up  answer I posted is confirmed working

Comment: the "magic" is to use #cloud-boothook. You can read more here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html and here: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html